# Unable to connect to the database with mySQL

Tags: mysql

i have created database file

```
export default {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    type: 'mysql',
    port: process.env.DB_PORT || 3306,
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    entities: ['src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    synchronize: process.env.DB_SYNCRONIZE === 'true',
    logging: process.env.DB_LOGGING === 'true',
  };
```

I am getting  error :Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
[image]

Comment: in mysql8, default authentication changed to caching_sha2_password. If you want previous standard support. then Need to create user with native password plugin.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL8, Default authentication mechanism has been changed to **caching_sha2_password**. If your drivers or client doesn't support then Create a new user with mysql_native_password mechanism and use that user in code. Please follow below command to create new user with native password.:

> CREATE USER 'nativeuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH
> mysql_native_password BY 'password';